# Extract text from txt file

Tags: vb.net

I've a txt file with many rows with this structure:

```
213008   DOMUS URBAN VILLAS                 09/04/13                    0-0 0 1-1-0                ED ML LC 10 MO PA 03 03    ED
```

There isn't tabulation, just spaces added by a third part software that generates this file.

Is there a way to extract every piece of text?

I mean, a way to obtain:

```
text_1 = 213008
text_2 = DOMUS URBAN VILLAS
text_3 = 09/04/13
```

Etc.

Comment: It seems to be a text file with fixed width columns. If it is so, then just a bunch of substring of the correct width

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me:

```
        Dim InputText As String = Replace(IO.File.ReadAllText(FileName), "  ", ",") 'two spaces
        Do Until InputText.Contains(",,") = False
            InputText = Replace(InputText, ",,", ",")
        Loop
        Dim Lines() As String = InputText.Split(",")

text_1 = Lines(0)
text_2 = Lines(1)
text_3 = Lines(2)
```

Comment: Sometimes I've one space, sometimes two or more. It seems that my file has fixed column as @Steve suggested in comments of my post.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.TextFieldParser` to parse text from file